# Publishing a iphone-only app to the app store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

When publishing an app to the app store, it was required to upload screenshots of both the iphone and the ipad for an ios app. When creating my ios app I wasnt focused on the ipad version so when I was opening the app through the ipad simulator the app was nothing to the iphone version.

I was wondering if **there is a way** to only **upload a iphone only app** to **the app store**. The most recent answer I could find was from a 5 years ago, wondering if that has changed since.

Comment: You have to select iPhone only in your Xcode project. iPhone only apps will still run on an iPad but in an iPhone sized screen. If you have already released a version on the App Store then it is too late; you cannot make your app iPhone only after a universal version has been made available

Answer (score 1):

From the Development Info section of Xcode you'll wan't to deselect everything other than iPhone. (In the following screenshot, both iPad and iPhone are selected).

[image]

This needs to be done prior to releasing a version of your app with an iPad version.

**If your application is already published OR is being tested on TestFlight**, this means that you specified iPad as an available platform when creating the app. You'll need to create a new app on App Store Connect. When you are doing that, make sure that iPhone is the only option selected for Platforms:

[image]

Comment: I looked at my Development info and I only have iPhone selected. The issue is when uploading my app to the App Store I am required to upload screenshots for the iPad too, I didn't account for my app to be on the size of an iPad so it looks all wonky. I feel like I'm messing something that I can't see. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Is your app already live on the app store?

Comment: No, but its live on test flight.

Comment: I've edited my answer, this should solve your problem.